# Accents package messing with kerning

Tags: spacing, accents

I had redefined the \vec command to remove kerning, and have noticed how after loading "accents" the kerning is back to normal (it is as if my redefinition of \vec was being ignored).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Accents
\usepackage{accents}

% Change kerning for vectors
\let\originalvec\vec
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\originalvec{\kern0pt #1}}

\begin{document}
$\vec{r}$
\end{document}
```

Any idea on what could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: show a complete example, not only a snippet. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: It is simply seeing the difference between $\vec{r}$ with and without "accents". Should I add an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\originalvec` is the version used by `accents`, which disregards the `\kern0pt` instruction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalvec}{\vec} % better than \let
\usepackage{accents}

% Change kerning for vectors
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\originalvec{\kern0pt #1}}

\begin{document}

$\vec{r}$

$\originalvec{r}$

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure you really want it, anyway.

[image]

Comment: That does it, thanks a lot!